# Como realizar a persistência de objetos em banco de dados no Delphi?

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, orientação-a-objetos

Trabalho com Delphi, mas sempre de maneira procedural e utilizando componentes Data-Aware. Recentemente comecei ler algumas coisas sobre como trabalhar com POO no Delphi, e fiz alguns exemplos bastantes básicos, minha dúvidas são estas:

Como posso trabalhar com uma classe (TClientes por exemplo) fazendo persistência na base de dados?
Como restaurar esses dados para visualização utilizando OO?
Como ficam os componentes Data-Aware?

Comment: Em relação aos componentes, eu sempre os crio em tempo de execução, existe uma classe de conexão que faz tudo isso...
Agora pra atualizar os dados é só trazer do banco novamente...

Comment: Sua dúvida é como inserir e retirar dados em um BD, como usar um determinado componente do Delphi, ou como fazer relacionamentos entre objetos e guardá-los em um BD de forma que seja possível restaurá-los adequadamente? Não ficou claro para mim.

Comment: @Math Na realidade a minha dúvida é de maneira geral sobre como posso trabalhar orientado a objetos em aplicações que utilizam bancos de dados. Em suma, como você disse "Como fazer relacionamentos entre objetos e guardá-los em um BD de forma que seja possível restaurá-los adequadamente?".

Comment: Essa sua pergunta é muito interessante. Eu mesmo fiz essa [mesma pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16447976/1964435) no SO.com faz um tempo e não obtive uma resposta decente. A sua dúvida é essa mesma? Se sim, de uma olhada no comentário que diz "Object-Relational impedance". Estou em horário de trabalho, vou tentar elaborar mais tarde.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os diagramas do seu BD e seu diagrama de classes ficarão muito parecidos, mas cuidado para não fazer confusão ao implementá-los, cada um funciona de um jeito bem diferente do outro e a quantidade de classes e tabelas não necessariamente são as mesmas.

Considere o seguinte exemplo para uma suposta classe `Cliente`:

[image: classe cliente]

```java
public class Cliente{
    private String nomeCliente;
    private String endereco;                //supondo que cada cliente só possui um endereco
    private List<String> telefones = 
            new ArrayList<String>();        //0..n telefones
    //construtor
    //getters and setters
}
```

Primeira dúvida: temos um `ArrayList` na classe `Cliente`, como guardamos isso no BD?

Nem pense em criar um zilhão de colunas na tabela `Clientes` no seu BD, assim: `telefone1`, `telefone2`, `telefone3`,  `...`, `telefone1000`. Assim você de cara já criou alguns problemas como um monte de colunas que na maioria das vezes nunca serão usadas, uma tabela horrível de se ler e de se criar um diagrama, e uma quantidade limitada de telefones do seu cliente (tá certo que é um limite alto, mas ainda assim é um limite).

O correto é você ter duas tabelas com o relacionamento `1..n`, assim você terá uma tabela para os clientes e uma para os telefones dos clientes. Fazendo assim não haverão registros não usados causando dificuldade na leitura das mesmas e não existirá um limite no número de telefones de cada cliente. As duas são ligadas por uma chave estrangeira na tabela dos telefones.

[image: tabelas bd]

Um exemplo de implementação de como carregar no `ArrayList` os telefones de cada cliente seria assim:

**método getCliente(String nomeCliente)**

```java
    prestat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE nomeCliente=?");
    prestat.setString(1, nomeCliente);
    pw = prestat.executeQuery();

    if (pw.next()) {
        //criando cliente
        cliente = new Cliente(pw.getString(2), pw.getString(3));

        // incluindo telefone do cliente
        cliente.setTelefones(getTelefonesCliente(pw.getInt(1)));
    }
```

**método getTelefonesCliente(int idCliente)**

```java
    List<TelefoneCliente> telefonesCliente = new ArrayList<TelefoneCliente>();

    //..

    prestat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TelefonesCliente WHERE idCliente=?");
    prestat.setInt(1, idCliente);
    pw = prestat.executeQuery();

    while (pw.next()) {
        telefonesCliente.add(pw.getString(3)));
    }

    //..

    return telefonesCliente;
```

E está resolvido o problema :)

Essa solução inclusive torna fácil a possibilidade de expansão do seu programa. Por exemplo, suponha que depois de implementado surge a necessidade de você precisar guardar a operadora do telefone do cliente.

Você tem duas opções:

- Pode criar mais um `ArrayList` na classe `Cliente`, entretanto na minha opinião ficaria um pouco estranho, e poderia inclusive ferir o princípio da responsabilidade única; ou
- Você pode fazer o que eu acho mais natural, criar uma classe nova:

[image: com duas classes]

Note que agora você terá duas classes e duas tabelas, mas o procedimento de carregar os dados nos objetos dessas classes é muito similar ao citado acima. Esse fica como dever de casa ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa de um framework [ORM](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional) para Delphi. Você pode desenvolver o seu ou usar um de terceiros. Algumas opções são:

- [TMS Aurelius](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/aurelius.asp) (comercial, só suporta versões mais recentes do Delphi por usar recursos como generics. É o que eu uso e recomendo. O principal desenvolvedor inclusive é brasileiro e pode te prestar suporte em português.)
- [tiOPF](http://tiopf.sourceforge.net/) (open source, um dos mais antigos)
- [DORM](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-orm/) (open source, um pouco mais recente, acho que também só suporta as versões mais novas do Delphi)
- [EntityDAC](http://www.devart.com/entitydac/) (comercial, anunciado estes dias, acho que ainda está em beta)
- [Synopse mORMot](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3%20Framework) (que sempre me falam bem, mas parece ser um pouco mais do que um ORM, por ter a parte de comunicação junto, e também nunca usei)

Comment: Adicione o [Synopse mORMot framework](http://blog.synopse.info/tag/mORMot) à lista. :)

Comment: @EMBarbosa bem lembrado!

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/orm-object-relational-mapping-delphi.htm